# Nishita with Ground

Tags: texturing, node-editor, world

Is it possible, using nodes, to combine a Gradient Texture and/or Color Ramp with a Nishita Sky Texture? Somehow I'm looking to combine the two, where below the horizon (or mountain range) the Gradient Texture is shown, and above it the Nishita Sky is shown. So perhaps some way to control the factor of the two whereby it dictates which is shown based on the Z, and combine them with a Mix Shader before plugging into the Background node.

One thing I've noticed, when plugging the Nishita into a MixShader it does grey everything out, so I don't know if this is truly the best approach, but I'm looking for something that achieves this.
[image]

Comment: looks like that is not possible